How do I handle and prevent race conditions in a multi-threaded Java application using ExecutorService?
I'm building a multi-threaded Java application where I need to run several tasks concurrently using ExecutorService. However, I'm encountering issues with race conditions when multiple threads try to access shared resources simultaneously.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
SharedResource sharedResource = new SharedResource();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
executor.submit(() -> {
    sharedResource.updateData();
});
}

executor.shutdown();


Is SharedResource  thread safe? What problems do you actually encounter?

The solution to this is to make your resources thread safe.  You're going to have to do that if you want any sort of multi threading, ExecutorService or no.

The more accurate term is data race, which is different from a race condition. There are various ways to prevent data races, and some may be preferred over others depending on your problem and requirements. However, the easiest way to do this is to make SharedResource.updateData synchronized. (public synchronized void updateData() {...})

https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety and https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/thread-safety.html

Either (a) protect access to the shared object (synchronized, locks, etc) or (b) make the shared object internally thread-safe. Very best solution is to avoid sharing mutable resources across threads.

FYI, your declaration SharedResource sharedResource should be marked final to prevent any other instance being assigned.
